# Clicking QPushButton through layered widgets

Tags: qt

I am trying to implement a series of layered widgets in Qt but having trouble with clicking "through" a top-level widget to one that is below

I have a standard main window that has a centralwidget, within this centralwidget I have a "button overlay" widget which contains a series of buttons around the side of the screen. The central widget then also contains a "display" widget within which I have a number of other widgets (In effect a way to display a center view with a series of buttons around the side)

However, I can only click on the buttons within the overlay, any buttons within the view don't receive the mouse click. I am assuming this is because although you can see the buttons in the layer below, it's the widget at the top layer that receives the mouse clicks which seems to be true as if I raise() the view to the top, the buttons can receive clicks

So, I there a way to click buttons through another widget or is my entire approach wrong?

Comment: With your reputation you must know that you must provide an MVCE

Comment: Overlaying widgets is a bad idea, you should layout them only. What's your need ? There is probably a better approach

Comment: Have you considered using a grid layout? This would allow you to have 5 layouts, top, left, bottom, right, and a large central one which spans multiple rows/columns